# Causal Inference from incomplete observation data

Tags: causality

A hypothetical pharmaceutical company organizes a poorly designed study as follows : It simply gives out its experimental drug to a pool of people with traits $X$. Only some of them are actually sick and the chance of them being sick depends on $X$. They **only** take the drug if they are sick, but doesn't necessarily do so (this is a mild disease and usually gets cured on its own). The company then get observational data (on all of them) about whether they have taken the drug or not and if they felt unsick afterwards, but doesn't get to observe if they were (or were not) sick to begin with. People who were unsick before, all report that they are unsick 'afterwards' too. How do I use this data to estimate $$P[Cured |X,D=1,T=1] - P[Cured |X,D=1,T=0]$$
where random variable $D$ and $T$ indicates whether they had the disease or not and whether they took the drug or not respectively?

*This probably is an impossible problem to solve without any additional assumptions. If so, what (reasonable) assumptions can I set, to make this problem tractable?*

Answer (score 0):

If I well understand,

1. you are comparing people that were sick and took vs those that were sick but didn't take the drug;
2. the decision to take the drug depended on their own.

Thus, simply calculating the difference between the two groups is prone to selection bias. To eradicate this bias, you should control for all factors that affect their decision to take the drug. By assuming a subset $Y$ of your $X$ variables includes such predictors, you could perform matching on all variables. However, in case of multiple variables, a propensity score analysis is more efficient. Of course, inference is limited to the population represented by the pool of people offered the drug in first place (as it would be even in case of a well-organized Randomized Controlled Trial) but, in this case, also by the region of overlap: https://ehsanx.github.io/psw/balance.html .
As highlighted here, in fact: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6714558/ , "propensity scores of zero or one are indicative of deterministic exposure so that causal effects cannot be defined for these subjects" (and the paper discusses in general the issue of estimating the PS in the areas close to the extremes, i.e. 0 and 1).

Comment: Thank you. My design matrix is fairly large and complete matching methods are probably not feasible. Could you elaborate a bit more on usage of propensity scores? If I understand them correctly, such methods gives me an estimate of $P[C=1|X,T=1]-P[C=1|X,T=0]$ which is different from the quantity in question if the chance of someone who's sick taking the drug depends on $X$ too.

Comment: in addition to chances of being sick depending on $X$, that is.

Comment: Yes,  the chance of someone who's sick taking the drug depends on the set of variables used to build the PS, by definition. I've tried to supplement my reply: let me know if it is fine for you. Of course the higher the number of observations with probabilities close to 0.5, the more precise estimates you'll get; the more you have observations whose PS is close to either 0 or 1 the less precise your estimates will be. The two extreme cases are: 1) PS=0.5 for all cases -> you have complete randomness, so you shouldn't have used PS in the first place; 2) PS = 0 or 1 for everyone: you can't use PS